# Formulario Email React

Tags: email, react, password

Fiz uma validação simples usando `react`, e gostaria que a mensagem 'b' só ficasse disponível quando o usuário clicasse em `submit`
como posso fazer?

```
export default class LoginApp extends React.Component {

  validarEmail=(e)=>{
       e.preventDefault();
       const email = e.target.elements.email.value;
       const password = e.target.elements.password.value.length;
       const emailValid = validator.isEmail(email)
       if(emailValid === false){
         console.log('email incorreto, favor verificar')
       }else if(password < 8 ){
          console.log('senha é muito curta, favor informar uma de maior numero de caracteres')
       }else{
         console.log('email e senha corretos')
       }
  }
    render() {  
      return (
        <div>
        <Header />
          <div className="container-app">
          <form method="get" name="modal_form" onSubmit={this.validarEmail}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Email address</label><br/>
              <input className="form-control" name="email"
              />
              {!!this.validarEmail.emailValid ? <p>a</p>:<p>b</p>}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label><br/>
              <input className="form-control" name="password"
              />
              {!!this.validarEmail.password < 8 ? <p>a</p>:<p>b</p>}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="button" >Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é utilizar estado. Começa com o estado de forma que a mensagem não esteja visível. O local mais apropriado para fazer isso é no construtor que ainda não tem definido:

```
export default class LoginApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.validarEmail = this.validarEmail.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            valido: false //iniciar estado de valido a falso (escondido)
        };
    }
```

Depois quando valida o email altera o estado de `valido` para `true`:

```
validarEmail=(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     const email = e.target.elements.email.value;
     const password = e.target.elements.password.value.length;
     const emailValid = validator.isEmail(email)
     if(emailValid === false){
       console.log('email incorreto, favor verificar')
     }else if(password < 8 ){
        console.log('senha é muito curta, favor informar uma de maior numero de caracteres')
     }else{
       console.log('email e senha corretos')
       this.setState(() => { /*altera o estado aqui*/
           return { valido: true };
       });
     }
}
```

No `render` agora mostra a mensagem apenas se `valido` estiver a true. Para simplificar pode utilizar o operador `&&` que é o mais comum em react:

```
render() {  
  return (
    <div>
    <Header />
    ...
    { this.state.valido && <p>b</p> }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o redux-forms que seu código vai ficar mais elegante e melhor para manutenção futura, veja um exemplo de validação com redux-form:

https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/syncvalidation/

Caso você tenha limitações e não possa utilizar o redux-forms, você pode utilizar o state para fazer este controle, se precisar ou post um exemplo aqui.